# Why photo excitation causes strong dipole transitions but the electron beam excitation causes non dipole transitions?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics

I am trying to understand the difference between electron-beam and laser excitation of a sample. A lot of papers discuss the optical excitation strongly couples to strong dipole modes but the electron beam transfer larger momenta to sample and hence causes non-dipole transitions. I am having a hard time understanding this concept. Can anyone please guide me on this?